# Avoiding duplicate image upload file to Parse.com in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, image-uploading

I have created a user profile edit page in the ViewController. When user edit only textfields and hit save button even though the picture is the same it will still upload it again. I want to check if the image is the same, skip the upload of the current image. Also parse uses same image file name so checking by name will not work, I have no idea what else to use. Any ideas?
Here is my code:

```
    let imageUploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageUpload.image!, 1)
        if (imageUploadData != nil) {
                //Here what I tried:
            if (currentImage.image != imageUploadData) {
                print("Image will be uploaded")
                let imageFileObject = PFFile(data: imageUploadData!)
                myUser.setObject(imageFileObject!, forKey: "license_image")
            }else {
                 print("Image is the same, skipping upload")
            }
        }
        myUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {(success: Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        self.clearAllNotice()  //Clear activity indicator

        if (error != nil) {
            print("...")
        }
        if (success) {
            print("Saving")
        }
```

What have I tried, mentioned in comments below

```
let userImageFile = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("license_image") as! PFFile
        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                if image == self.imageUpload.image {
                    print("image is the same")
                }
                else {
                    print("image not the same")
                }
            }
        }
```

I also tried this:

```
let userImageFile = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("license_image") as! PFFile
        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                let imageFileObject = PFFile(data: imageUploadData!)
                if ((image?.isEqual(imageFileObject)) != nil){
                    print("image is the same")
                }
                else {
                    print("image not the same")
                }
            }
        }
```

No luck

Answer (score 0):

Just get the data of the image that they already have saved, and compare it to the data of the image that's about to be saved, and if it's the same the don't allow them to continue or whatever your use case is.

Comment: I fixed the problem for now, I separated the task into different buttons